# Recording whole terminal screen using tee

Tags: bash, ssh, tmux, io-redirection, byobu

I am trying to get help from someone, so I want to record my screen to be able to later review what happened. Formerly, I have used `ssh` with `tee` like `ssh user@server | tee recfile` and the recording works fine. Even when I use `byobu` on the server, everything is recorded using that simple pipe.

But when I pipe `byobu` itself to tee, the file will contain pretty nothing. I have used both `byobu | tee recfile` and `byobu |& tee recfile`. In both cases, `byobu` starts and works well, but the record file will only contain a few lines not related to the things happened in byobu session.

And `byobu` uses `tmux`. I have tried to pipe `tmux` to `tee` as well, and the output file only contained `[exited]`.

My question is how `tmux` writes to the screen? It seems that it does not use standard output or standard error, as if it did, `tee` could work recording the screen. Is there a way to tell `tmux` to write to the standard output or standard error? Or is there another way to redirect the output to `tee`?

---

Edit: I checked that `screen | tee recfile` and `screen |& tee recfile` will produce an empty file. Also, `bash | tee recfile` will only redirect the output of executed commands to the file (`user@name:~$`'s and the input commands are not in there). `bash |& tee recfile` will do likewise, except that the prompt of the bash (`user@name:~$`) is not displayed at all.

Comment: Have you tried to use `script` to record your session?

Comment: `tmux` use buffers, so you can use [this workaround](https://ricochen.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/capture-tmux-output-the-much-less-painful-way/) to save your tmux session to a file.

Comment: You could use the tool `recordmydesktop` which has a gtk GUI as well that you can use to select specific windows to record.

Comment: @Yokai I don't want a video file as the output, I want a text file. This can be understood from the question.

Comment: You said in your question, and I quote, `I want to record my screen to be able to later review what happened.` so I provided a method of doing that. This can be understood by having reading comprehension of your own question.

Comment: Please don't... I have explicitly written my questions in the last paragraph. But thanks anyways. Maybe someday I come back to this page to take the name of the tool you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As gniourf_gniourf pointed out, `script` solved my problem.

I also wrote a simple C++ code to playback the recorded file. Compile it with `--std=c++11`. (I use `script -c byobu --timing=recfile.tim recfile` to record and `scriptout recfile recfile.tim 3` for playback.)

https://gist.github.com/Shayan-To/672c77fbf9811d769d453c8a9b43747e